# Firebase Auth test using Roboelectric keeps failing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, robolectric

When running this test I get null pointer exception. I checked if everything is fine with the button. So there is a problem with either roboelectric or firebase. I've got no idea why it is happening.

Everything is working fine when I do this by hand. User is created and activity changes.

Edit: UI tests using espresso work fine.

```
 @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
 @Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)


class RegisterUserTest {
    @Test
    fun shouldRegisterUser() {
        val activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(RegistrationActivity::class.java)

        val emailText = activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.text_email)
                .setText("example@example.com")
        val passwordText = activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.text_password)
                .setText("password123")
        val confirmPasswordText = activity.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.text_confirm_password)
                .setText("password123")

        val signupButton = activity.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_register)

        assertNotNull(signupButton)
        assert(signupButton.isEnabled)
        signupButton.performClick()


        assertNotNull(activity.firebaseAuth.currentUser)

        val actualIntent = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application).nextStartedActivity
        val expectedIntent = Intent(activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        assertEquals(expectedIntent.component, actualIntent.component)

    }
}
```

Inside my acitvity onCreate method I have assigned a listener.

```
btnRegister.setOnClickListener{
                registerUser(textEmail.text.toString(), textPassword.text.toString())
                val intent = Intent(this@RegistrationActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)

        }
```

That's the register method which uses Firebase Auth.

```
fun registerUser(email: String, password: String) {
        this.firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success")
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure")
                    }
                }
    }
```

Error stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdvv.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwc.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.daza.meter.RegistrationActivity.registerUser(RegistrationActivity.kt:154)
    at com.example.daza.meter.RegistrationActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(RegistrationActivity.kt:62)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at com.example.daza.meter.RegisterUserTest.shouldRegisterUser(RegisterUserTest.kt:41)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:568)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:253)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:130)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

Comment: Have you enabled authentication in Firebase Console?

Comment: Yes. I have enabled it. My app is working fine when I use it. My question is about testing Roboelectric. UI tests using espresso are working fine.

Comment: Having the same issue, could not find a solution yet